# How to know when user leaves Safari Mobile app?

Tags: php, ios, safari

Is there a way to know when a user pushes the Home button on iPhone and leaves the site?
And Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it this will work for your needs but just like Michael said, you can't detect when safari it self exits but you could use `onbeforeunload` and ajax to do something.  Not entirely sure if it fires when safari exits but its work a try.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS devices, they dont allow an app to monitor other application events. I think android is a little more flexible (never developed for android fyi)